# Является ли ошибкой выражение "утверждает о том, что"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Является ли выражение **"утверждает о том, что "** ошибкой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, это грамматическая ошибка: после глагола *утверждать* не может идти предлог *о*; вместо него следует использовать союз *что*.

Дело в том, что у некоторых глаголов нет предложного управления, есть только беспредложное. *Утверждать* — хороший пример этого.

Итак, верно: *Он утверждает, что прав*.